# getHeight() vs getPreferredHeight() what is the difference

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I know, that it is a stuped question. but I can't understand, what is the difference between getHeight() and getPreferredHeight() ?

When I must to use getHeight and when getPreferredHeight ?

:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely `getHeight` will get the actual current height and `getPreferredHeight` will get the preferred height, no? :-)

---

Actually, on further investigation, it appears [`getPreferredHeight`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#getPreferredHeight%28%29) is used by a layout manager so you can tell it what height you want your control to be.

The [`getHeight`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#getHeight%28%29) call returns the actual height which, presumably, can change if need be.